# How to insert file path reference in HTML table

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I'm having a problem with internal links in HTML tables in Docusaurus. I want to display complex tables, which are not supported in normal markdown, and insert references to other pages in table cells.

For example, an MDX file contains an HTML table with a link:

```
# Concept

This is a concept.

<table><tr><th>header</th><th>header</th></tr><tbody><tr><td><a href="../Concept1/concept1.mdx" >Concept 1</a></td><td> </td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

This file will result in broken link error. I cannot use normal markdown link and anchor element does not support file path.

In this case, how can I put markdown file path in a cell so that Docusaurus can generate proper URL?

Answer (score 0):

The following works in my test project:

```
# Concept

This is a concept.

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header</th><th>header</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td><a href="../Concept1" >Concept 1</a></td><td> </td></tr>
  <tr><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that I used the `../Concept1` path to reference the document. Since the document name is the same as the directory it's in, there is no need to include both in the path. The path will only contain the `concept1` part.

Comment: I did try this way. But I'm actually converting to mdx from another format (DITA with DITA-OT), the URL path may not always work due to nesting and filenames. That's why I need all links in file paths so Docusaurus can process them.